# What is the difference between @PrimaryKeyColumn and @PrimaryKey in Spring Data Cassandra?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I have recently started using Cassandra for my Spring Boot applications. I have always just used `@PrimaryKeyColumn` and `@Id` annotation to mark the Primary Key in the Java Class but yesterday I saw a github repos where people were using @PrimaryKeyColumn annotations with `@Id` annotation and some other repos where people are just using `@PrimaryKey` annotations.
What am I missing here, I feel so lost.

Answer (score 2):

A good example for this can be found in the Git repo for DataStax's [E-commerce workshop](https://github.com/datastaxdevs/workshop-ecommerce-app/).

Consider this table/PK definition:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  user_id UUID,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id));
```

As there is a single column defined as the primary key, the [UserEntity class](https://github.com/datastaxdevs/workshop-ecommerce-app/blob/main/backend/src/main/java/com/datastax/tutorials/service/user/UserEntity.java) only needs to use the `@PrimaryKey` annotation:

```
@PrimaryKey("user_id")
private UUID userId;
```

Now consider *this* table/PK definition:

```
CREATE TABLE cart_products (
    cart_id uuid,
    product_timestamp timestamp,
    product_id text,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (cart_id, product_timestamp, product_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (product_timestamp DESC, product_id ASC)
  AND default_time_to_live = 5184000;
```

`cart_products` uses three columns for its PRIMARY KEY: `cart_id` as the partition key; `product_timestamp` and `product_id` for the clustering keys.  So the [CartProductEntity class](https://github.com/datastaxdevs/workshop-ecommerce-app/blob/main/backend/src/main/java/com/datastax/tutorials/service/cartproducts/CartProductEntity.java) still uses the `@PrimaryKey` annotation, but it references the [CartProductsPrimaryKey class](https://github.com/datastaxdevs/workshop-ecommerce-app/blob/main/backend/src/main/java/com/datastax/tutorials/service/cartproducts/CartProductsPrimaryKey.java):

```
@PrimaryKey
private CartProductsPrimaryKey key;
```

Inside *that* class, the individual primary key columns are annotated with `@PrimaryKeyColumn`:

```
@PrimaryKeyClass
public class CartProductsPrimaryKey {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(
            name = "cart_id", 
            ordinal = 0, 
            type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED) 
    private UUID cartId;
    
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(
            name = "product_timestamp", 
            ordinal = 1, 
            type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, 
            ordering = Ordering.DESCENDING)
    private Date productTimestamp;
    
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(
            name = "product_id", 
            ordinal = 2, 
            type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, 
            ordering = Ordering.ASCENDING)
    private String productId;
```

Basically, the annotations used depend largely on the complexity of the primary key definition.

As for the `@Id` annotation, it serves the same function as `@PrimaryKey`.  This is mentioned in the [Spring Data Cassandra repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/main/src/main/asciidoc/reference/mapping.adoc#metadata-based-mapping).

> The @Id annotation tells the mapper which property you want to use for the Cassandra primary key. Composite primary keys can require a slightly different data model.